# Multiple AngularJS factories in one 'factories' object

Tags: angularjs, controllers, angularjs-factory, factories

I want to make a factory the same way I make a controller, by having a list of factory objects that do multiple things. in EX1(see code below) , I want to define multiple factories and store them all in one 'factories' object, and pass that list of 'factories' object into my controllers. The same way I do it in EX2, I define a 'controllers' object that holds my controllers and pass that into my demoApp.controllers. When I try to do what I have posted below I get this:
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/unpr?p0=factoriesProvider%20%3C-%20factories%20%3C-%20SimpleController

and I'm not sure why. Please Help! I will give you brownie points.

If there is a way to do this, I could really segregate out my code by having a 'factories.js' file that would house all my factories, another file, 'controllers.js' file that holds all my controllers, etc. That would simplify my code a lot.

EX1:

```
var factories = {};
factories.simpleFactory = function($http){
   var customers = [
      {name: "John Smith", city: "Phoenix"},
      {name: "John Doe", city: "New York"},
      {name: "Jane Doe", city: "San Francisco"}
    ];
   var factory = {};
   factory.getCustomers = function(){
      return customers;
    };

  return factory;
}
factories.notSimpleFactory= function($http){
   var someVariable = [1,2,3,4];
   var factory2 = {};
   factoryTwo.getSomeVariable() = function(){
       return someVariable;
   }
   return factory2;
}
demoApp.factory(factories);
```

EX2

```
var controllers = {};

controllers.SimpleController = function($scope,factories)
{
  $scope.customers= {}
  $scope.factory2Var = {}
  init();
  function init(){
    $scope.customers = factories.simpleFactories.getCustomers();
  }
  callNotSimpleFactory()
  function callNotSimpleFactory(){
       $scope.factory2Var = factories.notSimpleFactory.getSomeVariable(); 
  } 
   $scope.addCustomer= function(){
$scope.customers.push({name: $scope.newCustomer.name, city: $scope.newCustomer.city});
}};
demoApp.controller(controllers);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this at the end 
for controllers like bleow and same for factories

```
for (var prop in controllers) {
    demoApp.controller(prop, controllers[prop]);
}
```

Comment: But not, apparently, the answer